# How to check for NULL column, then do something, in prepared SELECT statement?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Here is the current code, but all it does is select the columns from 1 row.

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'sqlconnection.php';
$conn = OpenCon();

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT uid,coverphoto,profilepic,bio FROM profile WHERE uid = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['uid']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($uid,$coverphoto,$profilepic,$bio);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $output=array(
        'uid' => $uid,
        'coverphoto' => $coverphoto,
        'profilepic' => $profilepic,
        'bio' => $bio
    );
}
$json=json_encode($output);
echo $json;
$stmt->close();
CloseCon($conn);
?>
```

How do I add an if statement to this so that if coverphoto and/or profilepic = null, manually assign the value to coverphoto and profile pic for the output array? I will show my incorrect attempt below:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'sqlconnection.php';
$conn = OpenCon();

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT uid,coverphoto,profilepic,bio FROM profile WHERE uid = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['uid']);
if ($stmt->execute()){
   if (coverphoto=null){
     $coverphoto = 'coverphoto.jpg';
    }else{
     if (profilepic=null){
     $profilepic = "profilepic.jpg";
    }else{
$stmt->bind_result($uid,$coverphoto,$profilepic,$bio);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $output=array(
        'uid' => $uid,
        'coverphoto' => $coverphoto,
        'profilepic' => $profilepic,
        'bio' => $bio
    );
}
}
}
}
$json=json_encode($output);
echo $json;
$stmt->close();
CloseCon($conn);
?>
```

Comment: you need to continually push inside the loop. `$output[] = your array here`. currently you're just overwriting every iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have some syntax error.

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'sqlconnection.php';
$conn = OpenCon();

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT uid,coverphoto,profilepic,bio FROM profile WHERE uid = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['uid']);
$result = $stmt->execute();
if ($result){
   if ($result['coverphoto']){
     $coverphoto = 'coverphoto.jpg';
    }else{
     if ($result['profilepic']){
     $profilepic = "profilepic.jpg";
    }else{
$stmt->bind_result($uid,$coverphoto,$profilepic,$bio);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $output=array(
        'uid' => $uid,
        'coverphoto' => $coverphoto,
        'profilepic' => $profilepic,
        'bio' => $bio
    );
}
}
}
}
$json=json_encode($output);
echo $json;
$stmt->close();
CloseCon($conn);
?>
```

You can also do it this way

```
<?php
<?php
session_start();
include 'sqlconnection.php';
$conn = OpenCon();

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT uid,coverphoto,profilepic,bio FROM profile WHERE uid = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['uid']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($uid,$coverphoto,$profilepic,$bio);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $output=array(
        'uid' => $uid,
        'coverphoto' => $coverphoto ? $coverphio : 'coverphoto.jpg',
        'profilepic' => $profilepic ? $profilepic : 'profilepic.jpg',
        'bio' => $bio
    );
}
$json=json_encode($output);
echo $json;
$stmt->close();
CloseCon($conn);
?>
```

Comment: when i tried the first suggestion, i didnt work, i know the way i had it was totally messed up. but your second suggestion worked flawlessly. but i dont understand it whatsoever. could you explain it at all?

Comment: $coverphoto ? $coverphio : 'coverphoto.jpg' this code is a short hand of an If statement so this means if $coverphoto has a value then use $coverphoto else use 'coverphoto.jpg'

Comment: I updated my first answer, I did not notice a syntax error